# 2 nvidia display card with ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

I have a lenovo thinkstation p700 with 2 HP Z24n moniotr, both set as portrait.

I have a problem setting up 2 display card to make both works. 1st one is nvidia nvs 315, 2nd one is nvidia nvs 510. Now I can only use one monitor using 315 with one DVI.

If I use free driver from ubuntu, 315 works  but 510 doesn't work. I mean the display port never get detected. But at least the ubuntu can run with only one display as DVI. However, my monitor cannot set as portrait.

If I upgraded 315 using driver 390, I can setup the monitor as portrait. But still the 2nd monitor using display port is not detected.

But last time I keep 315 as free driver, and upgrade 510 using driver 470, it I can see the connection like display port or hdmi from 510 but once I try to set portrait. It seems not supported and again I got a black screen.

Please advise how I should setup?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use proprietary NVidia driver version 340 or 390, because they should provide support for both your NVidia cards. If you look at supported products you can see that driver version 470 does not support NVS 315 any more. Here are links with information:

- version 340: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156162/en-us/
- version 390: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/191119/en-us/
- version 470: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/191232/en-us/

I had a similar problem with an old NVidia card supported only by the legacy driver, and a new one supported only with the latest driver. There was no way to get them both working. If I loaded a legacy driver only the old card was working, and with the new driver only the new card was working.

I do not beleive both drivers can be installed together. I solved my problem by replacing the old NVidia with some cheap AMD graphics card. NVidia and AMD drivers can coexist, while two versions of NVidia driver cannot.

Comment: Hi Nobody, it is what I am doing now and I installed 390 and only 315 card works. But I don't like it...ummm
Thanks for the advise.